# Why can't I switch to CUDA?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I recently bought a new laptop, Gigabyte G5 with RTX 3060, so I want to set GPU as my rendering device. However, after switching from "none" to "CUDA" in the preferences, a warning window pops up and informs me that there is no compatible GPU.

Please tell me that I don't have to return my laptop

[image: warning]

Answer (score 1):

OK, if anyone have the same problem: the anwser was simple. I just didn't have NVIDIA studio drivers.